# JUnit - NullPointerException

Tags: java, junit, nullpointerexception, emokit

```
ContactDTO cDto = new ContactDTO();
cDto.setTitle("Mr");
cDto.setFirstName("Pritam");
cDto.setLastName("Mohapatra");
cDto.setTelephone("9439586575");
cDto.setEmail("pritam.pritam176@gmail.com");
cDto.setBetreff("test value");
cDto.setAnfrage("test value");

MessageTemplate messageTemplate=new MessageTemplate();
messageTemplate.setBody("Hallo ${name}.<br><br> want to contact ");
messageTemplate.setSubject("Refernce email");
when(emailProperties.getContactMsgKey()).thenReturn("4");
String key = "4";
when(messageTemplateService.getMessageTemplateById(key)).thenReturn(messageTemplate);
when(emailProperties.getAdminTo()).thenReturn("admin@gmail.com");

//String key = "3";
//when(messageTemplateService.getMessageTemplateById(key)).thenReturn(messageTemplate);
String to=emailProperties.getAdminTo();
String subject =messageTemplate.getSubject();
String body =messageTemplate.getBody().replace("${name}", cDto.getFirstName());
String contentType="text/html";
doThrow(NullPointerException.class).when(emailService).sendEmail(to, subject, body, contentType);
emailService.sendEmail(to, subject, body, contentType);
```

I am getting NullPointerException on Running JUnit Test. What am I
   doing wrong?
I am using this for email sending.

```
@Before
public void init() {

    emailService = mock(EmailServiceImpl.class);
    messageTemplateService =mock(MessageTemplateService.class);
    emailProperties=mock(EmailProperties.class);

    emailService.setEmailProperties(emailProperties);
    emailService.setMessageTemplateService(messageTemplateService);

}
```

- here is my @before method:

Comment: Maybe you should see and post the stacktrace as well :) It usually helps

Comment: where you initialize emailProperties and emailService ?

Comment: sorry I add the code.

Comment: The stack trace tells you exactly in which line of your code the exception happens. Please look at the stack trace to find out where exactly it happens. You might need to do more with your mocks, if you just create a mock without any behaviour the mock will probably return `null` when calling its methods, causing a NPE.

Comment: Using your actual contact details in the code snippet doesn't look like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you triger yourself the `NullPointerException` because of:

```
doThrow(NullPointerException.class).when(emailService).sendEmail(to, subject, body, contentType);
```

This instruction tells Mockito to throw a `NullPointerException`  when you call the `sendEmail` method on the `emailService` which is what you do directly after by calling:

```
emailService.sendEmail(to, subject, body, contentType);
```

Comment: Then How to call that emailService.sendEmail(to, subject, body, contentType);

Comment: Because it basically send the real message.